# Split ASP .Net Identity Entity across multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Is there a simple way to split ASP .Net Identity entities across multiple tables? I know you can change the name of the tables used by Identity using OnModelCreating.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("IdentityUser").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
    }
```

Can you similarly use an override in OnModelCreating or elsewhere to split across multiple tables? I tried using a map:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().Map(m =>
{
    m.Properties(t => new {t.Id, t.UserName});
    m.ToTable("User");
});
```

but I receive an error indicating UserName is already mapped. The non-key property 'UserName' is mapped more than once. Ensure the Properties method specifies each non-key property only once.

I assume this is due to the default mapping of Identity already having UserName mapped. Can I override this or remove the default mapping somehow in order to achieve splitting the IdentityUser entity across multiple tables?

Comment: Wait for a week, they're going to change all structures again, it will be Identity v.5 and will let you configure your authentication creating only 20 classes and overriding 80 methods... (ah, and don't forget interfaces, it has more than a thousand). And the best, this time it will be well documented.